# Codeigniter url redirection

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am developing an application on codeigniter whenever i try to visit the business controller it redirects to login page. This is the url http://www.atms.com.au/index.php/business. I cant find where the check for session variable is made for login
This is the controller

```
<?php
class Business extends Controller
{
    function Business()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->model('members_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata( $this->session_name, true) ;
        $this->session->set_userdata( "atms_member_login_id", $this->login_id);
        if($this->input->post('submit_business_info'))
        {           
            $business_name = $data['business_name'] = $this->input->post('business_name');
            $data['business_description'] = $this->input->post('description');
            $data['status'] = '1';

            if($_FILES['business_logo']['name'])
            {
                $prev_image = $this->input->post('prev_image');
                $logo = upload_image('business_logo', $this->config->item('business_logo_root'), array('dest' => $this->config->item('business_logo_root'), 'size' => array('w' => 127, 'h' => 127), 'ratio' => false), $prev_image);

                if($logo)
                    $data['business_logo'] = $logo;
                else
                    $data['business_logo'] = $prev_image;
            }

            $this->general_db_model->update('atms_members_info_tmp', $data, 'member_id = '.member_id());

            $member_detail = $this->general_db_model->getMemberDetail('atms_members_info', member_id());
        //debug_array($member_detail);
            $clinics = $this->input->post('clinic');

            if(!empty($clinics))
            {

                foreach($clinics as $key=>$clinic)
                {

                    if(array_values_exist($clinic))
                    {       

                        if($clinic_id = $clinic['clinic_id'])
                        {

                            unset($clinic['clinic_id']);
                            $this->general_db_model->update('atms_members_clinic_info_tmp', $clinic, 'clinic_id = '.$clinic_id);

                            $data['provider_no'] = 'updated';
                            $this->general_db_model->update('atms_members_info_tmp', $data, 'member_id = '.member_id());

                                        }
                                    else
                                {
                                $clinic['member_id'] = member_id();
                            $this->general_db_model->insert('atms_members_clinic_info_tmp', $clinic);
                            $data['provider_no'] = 'updated';
                            $this->general_db_model->update('atms_members_info_tmp', $data, 'member_id = '.member_id());

                        }
                    }
                }

                    $link = site_url()."/admin/members/update_details/".$member_detail->id;
                    $message = '';
                    $message.= 'Dear '.$business_name.',<br/><br/>';
                    $message.= $business_name.' had update business listing. So please approve it.<br/>';   
                    $message.= " Link: <a href='".$link."' > Update Link</a><br/>";             
                    $message.= 'Thank You.<br/>';                               
                    $subject = "Approve Update business listing.";

                    //$to = $this->settings->item('admin_email');
                    $to = $this->settings->item('admin_email');
                    $from =$member_detail->email;
                    //die($message);
                    $header = config_item('project_title');     

                    $this->my_library->send_email($to , $subject, $message, $header, $from);

            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message', 'Your business details successfully updated. Note: your updates must be approved by the administrator before displaying on the site.');
            redirect(current_url());
            die();
        }


        $data['info'] = $this->members_model->get_member_details(member_id());
        $data['clinics'] = $this->members_model->get_member_clinics(member_id());       
        $this->load->view('site/member/business_v', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php $this->load->view('site/inc/head');?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="headerWrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="top">
        <?php $this->load->view('site/inc/header');?>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <?php $this->load->view('site/inc/menu');?>
      </div>
      <div id="bannerIn" class="">
        <h1>Update My Details</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end #header -->
  <div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="page" class="clf">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="wideForm">
        <?php 
            global_message();
        ?>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="businessForm" name="businessForm">
        <ul class="clf">
            <li>
              <label>Business Name</label>
              <div class="inpWrapwide">
                <input type="text" class="text" name="business_name" id="business_name" value="<?php echo $info->business_name;?>" />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Add Logo</label>

                <div class="inpWrap file">
                    <input type="file" name="business_logo" id="addlogo" value="<?php echo $info->business_logo;?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="prev_image" value="<?php echo $info->business_logo;?>" />

                </div>
                <div style="padding:5px;"><em><?php echo $info->business_logo;?></em></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Description</label>
              <div class="txtWrap">
                <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="60"><?php echo $info->business_description;?></textarea>
              </div>
            </li>
            <?php 
            $count = 1;
            if(count($clinics) > 0) : 
                    foreach($clinics as $key=>$clinic):
            ?>
            <div id="clinic_<?php echo $count;?>">
                <li>
                    <h3 style="float:left;">Clinic <?php echo $key+1;?></h3>
                    <input type="hidden" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_id]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_id;?>" />
                    <span style="padding-left:10px;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="removeClinic(<?php echo $count;?>, <?php echo $clinic->clinic_id;?>);" class="remove_clinic"><img src="<?php echo config_item('site_images');?>close.gif" /></a></span>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Address 1</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_address_1]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_address_1;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">

                    <label>Address 2</label>
                   <div class="inpWrap">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_address_2]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_address_2;?>" />                                        
                   </div>
                </dd></dl>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Suburb</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_suburb]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_suburb;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">
                    <label>State</label>

                     <?php echo select_states('clinic['.$count.'][clinic_state_id]', $clinic->clinic_state_id);?>                                       

                </dd></dl>
                </li>

                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Postcode</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_postcode]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_postcode;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_telephone]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_telephone;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd></dl>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Mobile</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_mobile]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_mobile;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_email]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_email;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd></dl>
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Website</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_website]" value="<?php echo $clinic->clinic_website;?>" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                </dl>
                </li>
            </div>
            <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>    
            <?php else: 
            ?>
            <div>
                <li>
                    <h3>Clinic 1</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>City</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_address_1]" value="" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">
                    <label>State</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <?php echo select_states('clinic['.$count.'][clinic_state_id]');?>

                    </div>
                </dd></dl>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Postcode</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_postcode]" value="" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_telephone]" value="" /> 
                </dd></dl>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Mobile</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_mobile]" value="" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd class="lastItem">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_email]" value="" />                
                    </div>
                </dd></dl>
                </li>
                <li class="split">
                <dl class="clf">            
                <dd>
                    <label>Website</label>
                    <div class="inpWrap">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[<?php echo $count;?>][clinic_website]" value="" />                
                    </div>
                </dd>
                </dl>
                </li>
            </div>  
            <?php $count++;?>  
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div id="new_clinics">
                <!--appends new clinics here-->
            </div>
          </ul>

           <input type="button" class="add_clinic" value="Add more clinic" name="add_clinic" />
           <div class="buttons clf">
                <input type="button" class="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo current_url();?>';" />
                <input type="submit" class="update" value="update" name="submit_business_info" />
           </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end #content -->
      <div id="sidebar">
        <?php $this->load->view('site/inc/login_sidebar');?>
      </div>
      <!-- end #sidebar --> 

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end #page --> 
</div>
<div id="footerWrapper">
  <div id="footer">
    <?php $this->load->view('site/inc/footer');?>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end #footer --> 


<textarea style="display:none;" id="template">
<div class="transform" id="clinic_{0}">
    <li>
        <h3 style="float:left;">Clinic {0}</h3>
        <span style="padding-left:10px;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="removeClinic({0});" class="remove_clinic"><img src="<?php echo config_item('site_images');?>close.gif" /></a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="split">
    <dl class="clf">            
    <dd>
        <label>City</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[{0}][clinic_address_1]" value="" />                
        </div>
    </dd>
    <dd class="lastItem">
        <label>State</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
           <?php echo select_states('clinic[{0}][clinic_state_id]');?>               
        </div>
    </dd></dl>
    </li>
    <li class="split">
    <dl class="clf">            
    <dd>
        <label>Postcode</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[{0}][clinic_postcode]" value="" />                
        </div>
    </dd>
    <dd class="lastItem">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
       <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[{0}][clinic_telephone]" value="" /> 
       </div>         
    </dd></dl>
    </li>
    <li class="split">
    <dl class="clf">            
    <dd>
        <label>Mobile</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[{0}][clinic_mobile]" value="" />                
        </div>
    </dd>
    <dd class="lastItem">
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[{0}][clinic_email]" value="" />                
        </div>
    </dd></dl>
    </li>
     <li class="split">
    <dl class="clf">            
    <dd>
        <label>Website</label>
        <div class="inpWrap">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="clinic[{0}][clinic_website]" value="" />                
        </div>
    </dd>
    </dl>
    </li>
</textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.bannerLinks a').wrapInner('<span></span>');
     $("input[type=file]").filestyle({ 
     image: "<?php echo config_item('site_images');?>browse.gif",
     imageheight : 22,
     imagewidth : 68,
     width : 250
 });
 jQuery('.file div').hover(function(){
     //var _b = jQuery(this).attr("background");
     //jQuery(this).css("background","<?php echo config_item('site_images');?>browse_h.gif");
     }, function(){
         //jQuery(this).css("background","<?php echo config_item('site_images');?>browse.gif");
     });

    $("#businessForm").validate();  

    var template = jQuery.format($("#template").val());
    function addClinic() {
        $(template(i++)).appendTo("div#new_clinics");
        $('div.transform').jqTransform({imgPath:'<?php echo config_item('site_asset');?>jqtransform/img/'});
    }

    var i = <?php echo $count;?>;

    $(".add_clinic").click(addClinic);
});

function removeClinic(index, cid)
{
    if(cid)
    {
        if(confirm('Are You Sure?'))
        {
            $.post('<?php echo admin_url('members/remove_clinic_tmp');?>', {clinic_id : cid}, function(data){});
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    $('div#clinic_'+index).remove();

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am frustrated finding where the login check is made.
can anyone help me
Thanks

Comment: Please debug using die, line by line to find out from which line its redirect to login page let me know the result

Comment: Might be in the constructor of the parent class. I don't know the structure of that old CI version, it could be under system/core. ALso, if they had hooks in that version, it could be a pre_controller hook behing called to check the session

Comment: you are loading members_model and then accessing general_db_model... possible issue?  in most such cases it is a silent death.  things are being redirected to some other page possible as a default error handling configuration lower down in apache.

Comment: Please for Constructor name use __construct function, not same as class name - Business.. 
If you run/update your PHP on latest 5.3/5.4 this may be a problem!

You have to debug yourself to find out where is your problem, as @Elby said its best to use exit()/die and to find out where is that redirecting coming from.

! At CI you should be extending CI_Controller not Controller.

Comment: @Svetlio your last sentence is true only for the later version of CI (>2), older versions extend the Controller class

Comment: @DamienPirsy I don't see why any developer will use so old versions from CI and PHP(talking about the constructor).. but you are correct!

Comment: I am just using an old codeigmiter project to make change it ittle bit

Comment: Is it a new project or a exisiting project were you're working on? If it is an existing one, maybe a hook is placed before the constructor. More info about hooks: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: I am working on an existing project

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to go and have a look into the main Controller in the application/core. Maybe the Controller class is extended right there. Moreover, as it was also said, convert the old-style constructor to PHP 5+ __construct(). Try to set some breakpoints into your application to see where it goes and where it doesn't. I think that it should be related to an extension to the core controller.